# IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am facing "Failed to load Application context" while executing test cases and couldn't able to figure to the reason behind that. Below is the stacktrace that I got.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.ntrs.tct.external.model.AdapterTradecaptureModelApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must only contain valid chars
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId.<init>(EndpointId.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId.fromPropertyValue(EndpointId.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.expose.IncludeExcludeEndpointFilter$EndpointPatterns.<init>(IncludeExcludeEndpointFilter.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.expose.IncludeExcludeEndpointFilter.<init>(IncludeExcludeEndpointFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.expose.IncludeExcludeEndpointFilter.<init>(IncludeExcludeEndpointFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnAvailableEndpointCondition$Exposure.<init>(OnAvailableEndpointCondition.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnAvailableEndpointCondition.getExposures(OnAvailableEndpointCondition.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.OnAvailableEndpointCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnAvailableEndpointCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 48 more
```

Here is the code for my test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.yml" , "classpath:contract-test.properties"})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = {
        TradeCaptureServiceApplication.class })
@ActiveProfiles({ "local" })
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Slf4j
public class AgentContractTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
   
   
    @Test
    public void verifyAuthFail() {

    }

}
```

Could you direct me on what could be the reason behind the issue as I didn't write anything under testcase

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  But it is quite possible you should replace: `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

What are you using: `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` for?  I'm not sure what you're attempting to do.

Also, (without knowing context), you might not need:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = {
            TradeCaptureServiceApplication.class })
    @ActiveProfiles({ "local" })
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```